# How can i display filtered objects in Django template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Say I have an Model which displays as follows.

```
class Opt(models.Model):
    optID = models.CharField()
    availabiltities = models.ManyToManyField(Available)
    lastdatemodified = models.DateTimeField()
    ....
    ....
```

Also, opt_ID is not the primary_key

I want to be able to display all the field with respect to that opt_id in the html template. I have a page which displays all the Opt_id for that model. And each Opt_ID is a link which is supposed to display all the fields as I mentioned before...

In views.py I am currently writing,

```
def Optschedule(request, opt_id = 1):
   return render_to_response('show.html', {'OptSchedule', Opt.objects.filter(optID=Opt_id)})
```

In show.html

```
{% for entries in OptSchedule %}
    {{entries.lastdatemodified}}
    {{entries.availabilities}}
{% endfor %}
```

I guess, i am not understanding how do we pass arguments to the view function so that it uses those arguments for the queryset in views.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood your question, but you're missing some basics of Django

You can pass the arguments to your view in your request, configuring properly your urlconf.

But first, let's use lowercase for function names, as preconized by Python PEP8:

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

```
def opt_schedule(request, opt_id):
    opt_schedule = Opt.objects.get(id=opt_id)
    return render_to_response('show.html', {'OptSchedule': opt_schedule})
```

You're passing opt_id to your view, and this opt_id came from your urlconf, suppose:

```
(r'^show/(\d+)/$', opt_schedule),
```

this urlconf says that you're passing a decimal integer for your view opt_schedule, besides the request object. When you call www.example.com/show/1/, the view opt_schedule is called and receive request object and the decimal 1. Inside your view function, you're querying for Opt object that have the id (or pk) = 1, and passes it to your context with the name 'OptSchedule'

Now you can access your object attributes in your template, like:

```
{{ OptSchedule.lastdatemodified }}
```

Comment: Well, I tried this before, but it gives me an error saying Opt expects 2 arguments and you have supplied only one..which i could resolve. Now, when i use get(id=opt_id) it gives me: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: " . I think this is because the Opt_id is not an integer but is a Varchar. So, it does not fetch anything and is not able to convert it to int.